# how can I set a highscore in my tetris game javascript html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, tetris

I want to set a highscore with localstorage in my tetris game that I put in my website. I want that you can set a username and show it with the amount of score.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, If you want others to help you, Provide some more information. What have you made yet? What code do you have? What did you try? DId you do any research?

Comment: ok thank you Xun answered my question already. I've tried it but it confused me how I can set it in my game. I've take this answer serious and try to improve me for my next questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem("username1", 1);
                     //name , // score value
```